# Lower voice in Chopin's Nocturne Op 9 No 1 not adding up to 6/4 time signature

Tags: piano, rhythm, engraving, editions, rests

I wanted to learn Chopin's Nocturne Op 9 No 1. In most cases, the note values add up to the time signature of 6/4. However, in measure 6 of the right hand part, I counted the note values of the lower voice (stems point down) and it does not fully occupy a bar of 6/4 time.

[image: score with a measure "missing" a dotted half note rest]

How am I supposed to play it? On the version provided by [virtualsheetmusic.com](https://www.virtualsheetmusic.com), there is a dotted half rest to fill in the gap. MuseScore hides the dotted half rest. Why was MuseScore designed like that?

Comment: Don't really understand your question. Whoever used musescore to do the engraving must have chosen to hide the rest. Most editions exclude the rest, though some include it. You can browse many editions at https://chopinonline.ac.uk/ocve/. But question about how musescore was designed would have to be directed to musescore.

Comment: @Aaron "Most editions exclude the rest": do you know whether there are any sources that show whether Chopin included the rest?  (I'd guess that the omission reflects his practice because normally one would expect it to be included, but I don't have time right now to look myself.)

Comment: @phoog There is no autograph, but most editions, both on IMSLP and the Chopin Variorum, which is linked in my previous comment, omit the rest.

Comment: @Aaron I had assumed from your not having mentioned an autograph that none probably exists.  So the next questions would be whether Chopin participated in the preparation of any of these editions and perhaps the relative timing of those editions that include the rest and those that omit it. (In other words, sources other than autograph manuscripts may help answer the question.) Also since musescore is open source it is probably fairly easy to find information about design decisions.

Comment: @phoog Have at it.

Comment: M6? I see nothing wrong. It all lines up and counts perfectly. Play it so the notes aligned vertically go together. Anacruces are usually not counted as m1, though. Do you mean 1st bar on line 3?

Comment: @Tim, Good notation practice would allow you to read the top staff without benefit of the bottom staff, left to right *without having to work backward from the end of the measure to know when the Db comes in*. Alignment should reinforce and agree with note and rest values, not substitute for them. (Measure numbers here are printed for the first measure of each line. The first measure is assigned 1, even if incomplete, for reference purposes)

Comment: I am talking about measure 6.

Comment: @DjinTonic - not in my, or most other muso's world. So call anacrucis bar 0. 1st full bar generally known as bar 1.

Comment: @Tim You're right that the anacrusis shouldn't be counted as measure 1, but in this score the measure numbers are shown at the start of each line.

Comment: @Aaron as mentioned, no time just now.  I was hoping you'd noticed something relevant in your research.  As it seems you didn't, I'll continue to hope that someone else who reads this either knows or is curious enough to spend some time finding out.

Comment: @Tim I stand corrected. You are right  about measure numbering.

Answer (score 2):

A dotted half rest is not printed for the lower voice in the upper staff at the start of that measure, because it is unnecessary, and the score is much neater without it.  The pianist can see when to play that D-flat because it's at the half-way point in the measure; it lines up with the beam group in the lower staff.

> **Use of Rests**
> To keep the stave as uncluttered as possible, use rests sparingly for additional parts: when both hands are already playing the pianist  does not want to read extra rests, except to clarify the placing of additional parts that have independent rhythm.

— Gould, *Behind Bars* - Keyboard / Part-writing, pp. 311–312      ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Comment: "except to clarify the placing of additional parts that have independent rhythm": to my eye, at least, that is exactly why the rest is better included than omitted.

Comment: @phoog Perhaps the long note in the upper voice should be written as a dotted minim tied to a mimim tied to quaver?

Comment: I've played that many times, and it had never occurred to me to wonder when the second-to-top voice came in. There had _been_ no second-to-top voice until that moment. If I'd seen a half rest in that measure, I'd have wondered what it was about. :) For me, the vertical alignment in most editions of Chopin is what my eyes rely upon: how else to compare 11ths with anything else. :)

Comment: @ElementsinSpace A **dotted** half note tied to a **regular** half note tied to a **regular** eighth note is the way that Frédéric Chopin did it himself: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNtVK.png

Comment: @Vighnesh That does look neater for the top voice, doesn't it? But the rest at the start of the measure is still unnecessary clutter.  PS I'm not sure that really is Chopin's handwriting.

Comment: If you're a beginner, then learn from a version that _does_ include the dotted half rest to make it easier to play the first D♭ note in the lower voice.